# elasticsearch 1.7 group by bucket with multi field concat

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an aggregate statement that groups by `firstname` and buckets them with necessary fields. But I want to group by concatenation of `firstname+lastname`. I do not want to use nested aggregates like group by `firstname` and then group by `lastname`. How do I change the field to include a string concatenation of multiple fields?

```
"aggs": {
    "by_name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "firstname"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "source": {
          "top_hits": {
            "_source": {
              "include": [
                "id","name"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ES 1.7

You may use [script aggregation with terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-script)

```
GET _search
{
  "size": 20,
  "aggs": {
    "con": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "doc['firstName'].value + doc['lastName'].value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For current version, ie. ES 5.2, there is [bucket script aggregaton](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-script-aggregation.html) for the same purpose

Comment: Ah I was trying to use this but apparently I missed `"lang":"groovy"` in the terms so it was throwing errors.

Comment: is there a way to use mustache to do the same thing?

Comment: No idea about mustache scripting.. but should be possible